# Whenever handlers executed need to push message to zeromq stays hanging

Tags: python, tornado, zeromq, pyzmq

I have nginx in front of 8 instances of Tornado, and for some requests (a handler for comments), I need Tornado to push messages on ZeroMQ. I am doing this at the end of the handler (just before I send the response to the client):

```
    # here is body of handler for comments 

    context = zmq.Context()
    port = "5252"
    socket = context.socket(zmq.PUSH)
    socket.bind("tcp://*:%s" % port)
    print "Running server on port: ", port
    socket.send("Commented")

    # here I flush response to client
```

But this is hanging. Is this real way to push to ZeroMQ whenever the handler is executed?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this real way to push to ZeroMQ whenever the handler is executed?

No. Your code calls zmq.Context() every time the request handler is invoked.  This is bad.  It should be called exactly once - usually at the very beginning of your process, perhaps in some kind of init handler.  You can safely share the context instance among any number of threads.

Same thing with socket creation and binding - this should be done once at startup.  You must be more careful with the socket.  If all your handlers (application, request etc) are executing in the same thread each time the handler is called, then you can use the same socket.

Another problem is the way your a "send"-ing to a PUSH socket. As described in [http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-socket](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2%3azmq-socket), a send to a PUSH socket may very well block in certain situations and you probably want to avoid that.  Use the zmq.Poller with the POLLOUT flag (and a 0 timeout) to determine if the send would block.  If not, then send right away. If so, you have to decide if you want to just drop the message or store it in your application to try again later.